# How to zoom in/out in react-native-map?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using `react-native` to build a map application. The api I am using is from this link: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps.

Below is the code I bring the map on my app. I wonder how I can give a zoom value on that map. And how I can change the zoom value when the user clicks a button on the map.

What is the zoom API I should use to achieve this?

```js
import React, { Component, StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";

class MapPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude: 4.21048,
        longitude: 101.97577,
        latitudeDelta: 10,
        longitudeDelta: 5,
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputText}>Map</TextInput>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          mapType={"standard"}
          region={this.state.region}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          showsScale={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = MapPage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  inputText: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    flex: 4,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#48BBEC",
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: "#48BBEC",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You should use the `animateToRegion` method (see [here](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods))

It takes a region object which has `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`. Use these to set the zoom level.

**Updated:**

in a `Region` object the `latitude` and `longitude` specify the center location and `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` specify the span of the viewable map area.

This image from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190803112958/http://troybrant.net:80/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/) blog post illustrates it well (LatΔ and LngΔ).
[image]

Comment: what is the different between latitude and latitudeDelta? Is there a document to explain them?

Comment: Thanks for response. Is there any example to illustrate how to use animateToRegion?

Comment: Yes, see this example: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DisplayLatLng.js#L41

Comment: So, how to set deltas using custom zoom in and zoom out buttons?

Answer (score 4):

New React Native Maps API gives you option to call `animateCamera` method with `zoom` parameter.

```js
    const MapComponent= (props: any) => {
    
    const map: LegacyRef<MapView> = useRef(null);
    
    const onZoomInPress = () => {
        map?.current?.getCamera().then((cam: Camera) => {
            cam.zoom += 1;
            map?.current?.animateCamera(cam);
        });
    };
    
    return (
            <View>
                <MapView
                    ref={map}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    region={region}>
                </MapView>
                <ButtonComponent
                    style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 400, left: 0}}
                    onPress={onZoomInPress}>
                    Zoom In
                </MainButtonBlue>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IOS

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work using `Dimensions.get('window');`

```js
    const window = Dimensions.get('window');
    const { width, height }  = window
    LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUD_DELTA + (width / height)
```

and by default set `LATITUD_DELTA = 0.0922`.
Then just update this values with the prop `onRegionChangeComplete` in the `<MapView>`

Comment: How come it gives you different values? It refers to the screen size which is constant irrespective of the map zoom level

Comment: I think it should be LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUD_DELTA * (width / height)

Comment: @Shanaka why u say that?

Comment: This approach is used in this example: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DisplayLatLng.js#L12

Comment: How did we end up with LATITUD_DELTA = 0.0922? what does this mean? How do we calculate this?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const handleZoomIn = () => {
  map.current?.getCamera().then((cam: Camera) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      cam.zoom += 1;
    } else {
      cam.altitude /= 2;
    }
    map.current?.animateCamera(cam);
  });
};

const handleZoomOut = () => {
  map.current?.getCamera().then((cam: Camera) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      cam.zoom -= 1;
    } else {
      cam.altitude *= 2;
    }
    map.current?.animateCamera(cam);
  });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Should take a minute to explain your code instead of a code dump.

Comment: Hello, where should be the code placed? Please add some text.
[How to give good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: this is for functional component. call both this functions for your custom created zoom in and out button

Comment: <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 150,
          left: 10,
          backgroundColor: '#1f38d4',
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 8,
          elevation: 10,
        }}
        onPress={() => {
          handleZoomIn()
        }}>
        <FontAwesome5
          name="plus"
          size={20}
          color="#fff"
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

Comment: It should perhaps be explained that cam.altitude only works when you are using the iOS MapKit

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it worked out for me very well:

```js
function getRegion(origin, destination, zoom) {
  const oLat = Math.abs(origin.latitude);
  const oLng = Math.abs(origin.longitude);
  const dLat = Math.abs(destination.latitude);
  const dLng = Math.abs(destination.longitude);

  return {
      latitude: (origin.latitude + destination.latitude) / 2,
      longitude: (origin.longitude + destination.longitude) / 2,
      latitudeDelta: Math.abs(oLat - dLat) + zoom,
      longitudeDelta: Math.abs(oLng - dLng) + zoom,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me in conjunction with useRef on the MapView using react-native and expo. I use this function in a setTimeout of about 1000ms just so that the map loads and then animate to correct zoom level using your getRegion implementation

Answer (score 0):

I created the following based on the mercator math in https://github.com/tuupola/php_google_maps

The key function is `mercatorDegreeDeltas(latitude, longitude, width, height, zoom)` which returns `{ latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta }` for the specified latitude/longitude center point, map dimensions, and zoom level (1-20).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { useBottomTabBarHeight } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';

const MERCATOR_OFFSET = Math.pow(2, 28);
const MERCATOR_RADIUS = MERCATOR_OFFSET / Math.PI;

function mercatorLatitudeToY(latitude) {
  return Math.round(
    MERCATOR_OFFSET - 
    (
      (
        MERCATOR_RADIUS *
          Math.log(
            (1 + Math.sin(latitude * (Math.PI / 180))) /
            (1 - Math.sin(latitude * (Math.PI / 180)))
          )
      ) / 2
    )
  );
}

function mercatorLongitudeToX(longitude) {
  return Math.round(
    MERCATOR_OFFSET +
      (
        (
          (MERCATOR_RADIUS * longitude) * Math.PI
        ) / 180
      )
  );
}

function mercatorXToLongitude(x) {
  return (
    (
      (x - MERCATOR_OFFSET) / MERCATOR_RADIUS
    ) * 180
  ) / Math.PI;
}

function mercatorYToLatitude(y) {
  return (
    (
      (
        Math.PI / 2
      ) -
        (2 * Math.atan(
              Math.exp(
                (
                  y - MERCATOR_OFFSET
                ) / MERCATOR_RADIUS
              )
            )
        )
    ) * 180
  ) / Math.PI;
}

function mercatorAdjustLatitudeByOffsetAndZoom(latitude, offset, zoom) {
  return mercatorYToLatitude(mercatorLatitudeToY(latitude) + (offset << (21 - zoom)));
}

function mercatorAdjustLongitudeByOffsetAndZoom(longitude, offset, zoom) {
  return mercatorXToLongitude(mercatorLongitudeToX(longitude) + (offset << (21 - zoom)));
}

function mercatorDegreeDeltas(latitude, longitude, width, height, zoom) {

  if (!zoom) {
    zoom = 20;
  }

  const deltaX = width / 2;
  const deltaY = height / 2;

  const northLatitude = mercatorAdjustLatitudeByOffsetAndZoom(latitude, deltaY * -1, zoom);
  const westLongitude = mercatorAdjustLongitudeByOffsetAndZoom(longitude, deltaX * -1, zoom);
  const southLatitude = mercatorAdjustLatitudeByOffsetAndZoom(latitude, deltaY, zoom);
  const eastLongitude = mercatorAdjustLongitudeByOffsetAndZoom(longitude, deltaY, zoom);

  const latitudeDelta = Math.abs(northLatitude - southLatitude);
  const longitudeDelta = Math.abs(eastLongitude - westLongitude);

  return { latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta };
}

// Somewhat arbitrarily, Riverside Park, Independence, KS 67301
const CENTER_UNITED_STATES = {
  latitude: 37.24435373025407,
  longitude: -95.70234410503208,
};

export default function MapViewWrapper() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const tabBarHeight = useBottomTabBarHeight();
  const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
  const initialRegion = React.useRef(null);
  const availableHeight = height - tabBarHeight - headerHeight;

  // Only calculate initial region once
  if (!initialRegion.current) {
    const { latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta } = mercatorDegreeDeltas(
      CENTER_UNITED_STATES.latitude,
      CENTER_UNITED_STATES.longitude,
      width,
      availableHeight,
      4,
    );
    
    initialRegion.current = {
      latitude: CENTER_UNITED_STATES.latitude,
      longitude: CENTER_UNITED_STATES.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
      longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta,
    };
  }

  return (
    <MapView
      initialRegion={initialRegion.current}
      style={{ width: width, height: availableHeight }}
    />
  );
}
```

There is at least one issue: if you change the zoom from `4` to `3`, it isn't centered properly, but larger zoom values work. I don't need the lower zoom values right now, so I haven't investigated the math any further (maybe some sort of overflow?).

Answer (score -1):

[Example of Pinch to Zoom Image in React Native](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-pinch-to-zoom-image/)

```js
// Import React in our code
import React from 'react';

// Import all the components we are going to use
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

// Import ImageViewer which will help us to zoom Image
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';

const App = () => {
  const images = [
    {
      url:
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/sample_img.png',
    },
    {
      url:
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/old_logo.png',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageViewer imageUrls={images} renderIndicator={() => null} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```