# Get current location, latitude and longitude in ReactNative using react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am developing a map location. When I click in some particular place I get the latitude and longitude, but not the current location, latitude and longitude.

I don't know how to find out.

How can I get them and how can I put the marker at that position?

Here is my code:

```
class Maps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude:       LATITUDE,
        longitude:      LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta:  LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
      marker: {
        latlng:{
          latitude:       null,
          longitude:      null,
          latitudeDelta:  LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
      (position) => { alert("value:" + position) },
      (error)    => { console.log(error) },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout:            20000,
        maximumAge:         10000
      }
    )
  }

  onMapPress(e) {
    alert("coordinates:" + JSON.stringify(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))
      this.setState({
        marker: [{ coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate }]
      })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexGrow:1}}>
          <MapView
            ref="map"
            provider={this.props.provider}
            style={styles.map}
            onPress={this.onMapPress.bind(this)}
            provider = {PROVIDER_DEFAULT}
            mapType="standard"
            zoomEnabled={true}
            pitchEnabled={true}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            followsUserLocation={true}
            showsCompass={true}
            showsBuildings={true}
            showsTraffic={true}
            showsIndoors={true}>
          </MapView>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: follow this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I did it following these steps using `react-native@0.42.3` and `react-native-maps@^0.13.1` and using `react-native@0.44.0` and `react-native-maps@^0.15.2` at the date:

Set a `mapRegion` object in the `state`, the last `longitude` and the last `latitude` as `null`:

```
state = {
  mapRegion: null,
  lastLat: null,
  lastLong: null,
}
```

Then within your `componentDidMount()` function watch for each change in the current position:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

When there are changes update them in your `this.state.mapRegion`, passing the actual coords and the `delta` values (mine can be different to yours, so adapt them):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      // Create the object to update this.state.mapRegion through the onRegionChange function
      let region = {
        latitude:       position.coords.latitude,
        longitude:      position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta:  0.00922*1.5,
        longitudeDelta: 0.00421*1.5
      }
      this.onRegionChange(region, region.latitude, region.longitude);
    }, (error)=>console.log(error));
  }
```

Then you need the `onRegionChange()` function, that's being used to "set" new values to your elements within the `componentDidMount()` function:

```
  onRegionChange(region, lastLat, lastLong) {
    this.setState({
      mapRegion: region,
      // If there are no new values set the current ones
      lastLat: lastLat || this.state.lastLat,
      lastLong: lastLong || this.state.lastLong
    });
  }
```

Unmount the geolocation on `componentWillUnmount()`:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }
```

And render the `MapView` passing your current `mapRegion` object, the `MapView.Marker` inside of it is just to show you the current `latitude` and `longitude` when they change:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.mapRegion}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followUserLocation={true}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}>
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: (this.state.lastLat + 0.00050) || -36.82339,
              longitude: (this.state.lastLong + 0.00050) || -73.03569,
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>
                { this.state.lastLong } / { this.state.lastLat }
              </Text>
            </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Add the [StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/202dfcb6c4-absolute-fill-component-in-react-native) for your map in order to render it properly using the whole width and height of your device.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  }
});
```

So for your `onPress()` function you could do something similar to the `onRegionChange()`, that's to get the actual coordinates and to set them:

```
  onMapPress(e) {
    let region = {
      latitude:       e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
      longitude:      e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude,
      latitudeDelta:  0.00922*1.5,
      longitudeDelta: 0.00421*1.5
    }
    this.onRegionChange(region, region.latitude, region.longitude);
  }
```

Check the full code on [expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/Sk7Ch1eae) (although `react-native-maps` isn't installed)

Comment: Thnaks For your response , How can I get Current Location I  Followed Your code But  not show Currentlocation

Comment: And one more Thing When i was click particular location It's full Zoom ,just i want show the location  no need zoom how can i remove it Zooming also

Comment: You could set the `zoomEnabled` props to false, check [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) to see all the options available.

Comment: No Actually I used Property gave true  it's more ZoomEnabled

Comment: watchPositionImplAsync in LocationModule.java: 298, anyone??

Comment: Could you create a new question with the full stacktrace and error?

Comment: What are the magic numbers 0.00922, 0.00421, and 1.5? And magic numbers 0.00050, -36.82339, and -73.03569?

Comment: is it calling when i move on 
i mean change location every second or time?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to read this official documentation about geolocalisation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Then, with the current location, you can put that information into your state:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.setState({position: {longitude: position.longitude, latitude: position.latitude}});
}, (error) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error))
}, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 20000,
    maximumAge: 1000
});
```

You will be able next, in your render method, to compose your final view with a marker:

```
render() {
  return (
    <MapView ...>
      <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={this.state.position}
        title="title"
        description="description"
      />
    </MapView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...But,  I want Current position lat and long

Comment: when i was click touch displayed lat long and show marker

Answer (score 1):

Look for location permission using the following code:

```
try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        alert("You can use the location")
    }
    else {
        alert("Location permission denied")
    }
}
catch (err) {
    console.warn(err)
}
```

Fetch the current location latitude and longitude using the following code:

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    let region = {
        latitude:       position.coords.latitude,
        longitude:      position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta:  0.00922*1.5,
        longitudeDelta: 0.00421*1.5
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the magic numbers 0.00922, 0.00421, and 1.5? ([Sebastian Palma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176862/get-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-reactnative-using-react-native-m/43188042#43188042) also has the magic numbers)

Comment: Hi, these are not the magic number. this totally depends upon your requirement. Here I have mentioned a random number.  you can find this link helpful to undertand the concept of latitudeDelta  and LogitudeDelta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685372/how-to-zoom-in-out-in-react-native-map/36688156#36688156

Comment: You can think like these values used to zoom in and zoom out the map. latitudeDelta is the difference between the latitude and similar for the longitude according to a map showing in the map. You can see a demo of this in above-mentioned link

Comment: You can also visit google map api documentation for more info