# accessing the index without using bind

Tags: react-native

I am looping over an array and everytime the text at the index is clicked , i get it printed but i am using bind everytime .How can we do it without bind and just es6.

```
for(let index=1;index<=10;index++){
            arr.push(
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    key={index}
                    onPress={this.Updatefunction.bind(this, index)}
                >
                    <Text>
                        {index}
                    </Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
```

i want to access the index but don't want to do binding.

Answer (score 0):

> You can go with the additional syntax

like use arrow function,

```
for(let index = 1; index <= 10; index++){
            arr.push(
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => this.Updatefunction(this, index)}
                >
                    <Text>
                        {index}
                    </Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
```

Here each time render is called an anonymous function is created and that function when called, calls this.onClick.

However consider the case below
your function look like

```
Updatefunction = (this, index) => {
    // your code here
}
```

In above case, the arrow function does not recreate function everytime, but binds the context to the React component as An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used. once when the class is instantiated. This is similar to how  binding works is constructor. This is a part of proposed class fields for arrow functions and it isn't a ES6 feature,

Comment: I've seen you've added an improvement to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176862/get-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-reactnative-using-react-native-m/43188042#43188042). I hope you can add more than just the code to explain the how and why of that part of code to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the ES6 way to define your functions which are arrow functions and then call it like this

```
for(let index=1;index<=10;index++){
            arr.push(
                <TouchableOpacity
                    activeOpacity={0.7}
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => this.Updatefunction(this, index)}
                >
                    <Text>
                        {index}
                    </Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
```

And define your function like

```
Updatefunction = (this, index) => {
// your code here
}
```