# Zooming In using React Native Maps in IOS not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Zooming in and out with Android is pretty easy and works totally fine; however, the result is pretty much different with IOS. I can not zoom the map in to align the map view like what I have in Android.

I set my deltas to:

```
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.000894375;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.000894375;
```

And I am using:

```
  region: new MapView.AnimatedRegion({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
  }),
```

For both IOS and Android. Though I found this answer:

[how to zoom in/out in react-native-map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685372/how-to-zoom-in-out-in-react-native-map)

But I am not sure if `AnimateToRegion` and `AnimatedRegion` are the same thing. If not, I am not sure how to implement the `AnimateToRegion`.

Please advise thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `AnimatedRegion`, but you can use `AnimateToRegion` like following:

```
this.refs.map.animateToRegion({
      latitude: latitude, 
      longitude: longitude, 
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA, 
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA}, 
      duration)

<MapView style={{flex: 1}}
          ref="map"
          ...
          >
```

I found duration of 3000 suitable for my use.

Comment: It did not work . . the error says **Cannot read property 'animateToRegion' of undefined** this maybe because there is not **animateToRegion** when I console log the **this.refs.map** . . I am now using **MapView.Animated**, should I remove Animated and use MapView only?

Comment: I am using the version 0.13.0 of react native maps

Comment: Did you put `ref="map"` into your MapView?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake. You must have put `ref="map"`, otherwise you would get `undefined`.

Comment: Yes I added **ref="map"** on my MapView . . I am using react native maps version 0.13.0 . . Should I put the **this.refs.map.animateToRegion** inside **componentDidUpdate**?

Comment: I tried it on android and added you code inside **componentDidUpdate**, now I get a different error saying **this.refs.map.animateToRegion is not a function** :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Urska it is now working, no more errors . . I changed **MapView.Animated** to **MapView** and it is now working . . :)