# Get latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta from viewport in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have this data and I want to get `latitudeDelta/longitudeDelta` too

```js
geometry:{
    location:{
        lat:35.7212504,
        lng:51.36276979999999
    },
    viewport:{
        northeast:{lat: 35.7290254, lng: 51.380868},
        southwest:{lat: 35.7004529, lng: 51.3492823},
    }
}
```

I'm going to get `latitudeDelta/longitudeDelta` with this data
Of course, I would say that I use `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` and this data is output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;

const lat = details.geometry.location.lat;
const lng = details.geometry.location.lng;
const latDelta = details.geometry.viewport.northeast.lat - details.geometry.viewport.southwest.lat;
const lngDelta = latDelta * ASPECT_RATIO;

let coordinate = {
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: lng,
    latitudeDelta: latDelta,
    longitudeDelta: lngDelta
};
```

Comment: These links helped me a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685372/how-to-zoom-in-out-in-react-native-map/36688156#36688156    AND http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/  AND https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DisplayLatLng.js#L41

Answer (score 1):

If by "*from viewport*" you mean "*what the map is currently showing at it's latitude-longitude position and current zoom level (latitude and longitude deltas)*", you can:

As Exilz said in [his comment on a github issue](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/505#issuecomment-243393425://)

...the region value can be acquired with the event `onRegionChangeComplete`.

If you want to zoom programmatically on anything, you can use the method `animateToRegion` and pass the coords, and the deltas you got from `onRegionChangeComplete`. You just have to find your desired "zoom" by pinching the map, and note down these values.

Here's his sample of code to center / zoom the map on one of his markers :

```
onPressMarker (markerData) {
    this.setState({ openedMarker: markerData });
    this.refs.map.animateToRegion({
        latitude: parseFloat(markerData.latitude),
        longitude: parseFloat(markerData.longitude),
        latitudeDelta: 0.0043,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0034
    });
}
```

I mostly copied his content, so I urge you go to the github issue and like his comment.