# Expo location crash on android when navigating with fetched coord navigation payload

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am using expo location and I want to navigate into a map[ view page after I fetched the coords object. My goal is that when I press a button, I will be prompted to my location with zoom at an acceptable level...

The code are working for IOS, but android is crashing constantly. I am using expo go application.
The following code receives a prop with the location from the EXPO location package and the initial region is set to the coords.

```js
export default function Map({ route, navigation }) {

  const { location } = route.params;
    
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map} 
        initialRegion={{ 
          latitude: location?.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location?.coords.longitude
        }}
        
        // minZoomLevel={10}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        showsUserLocation={true}
      /> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

In the fllowing code, I ask for the permissions and return true if I have the relevand approval. Than, in the `handlePickupLocationOnMap` function I ask for permission and get the current position. Than, if I have the location, navigate to the map screen.

```js
const [locationPermissionInformation, requestPermission] = useForegroundPermissions();

const verifyPermissions = async () => {
  if (locationPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.UNDETERMINED) {
    const permissionResponse = await requestPermission();
    return permissionResponse.granted;
  }

  if (locationPermissionInformation.status === PermissionStatus.DENIED) {
    Alert.alert('You need to allow this app to get your location for a good use')
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}


 /**
 *      Use the location coords object and push it to the map aerial view
 *      Execute the navigation function only after the MapView has the location
 */
 const handlePickupLocationOnMap = async () => {
  let  hasPermssion = await verifyPermissions();

  if (!hasPermssion) {
    return;
  }
        
  const location = await getCurrentPositionAsync();
  location && navigate.navigate('MapView', { location });
 };
```

Comment: can you asset suggested solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While React Navigation share data between 2 screens. Data (params) are serialized (converted to string).

Android Google Map SDK expects coordinates to be FLOAT not serialized STRING values.

The solution is always cast coordinates values to FLOAT.

```js
export default function Map({ route, navigation }) {
  const { location } = route.params;

  const getInitialRegion = () => {
    // A defaul region of map. Mostly in area close to your userbase.
    const initialRegion = {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    };

    let latitude = location?.coords?.latitude;
    let longitude = location?.coords.longitude;

    if (latitude && longitude) {
      // Imperatively, coordinates values must be FLOAT
      latitude = parseFloat(latitude);
      longitude = parseloat(latitude);
      const region = { ...initialRegion, latitude, longitude };
      return region;
    }

    return initialRegion;
  };

  const initialRegion = getInitialRegion();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={initialRegion}
        // minZoomLevel={10}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        showsUserLocation={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you. I cant understand latitude delta btw...

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Someone tried to explain that concept here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685372/how-to-zoom-in-out-in-react-native-map/36688156#36688156